# How can I change this Scala regex so the the parentheses are excluded?

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to capture only `Some({what: ever })` but the regex I use always gives me the extra parentheses around it.

`scala> "\\((.+)\\)".r.findFirstIn("data: ({what: ever })")
res30: Option[String] = Some(({what: ever }))`

Comment: A simple solution could be `\{[^}]*\}`.

Comment: Thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\{[^}]+\}
```

or escaped

```
\\{[^}]+\\}
```

[See it here at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1jO8KD).

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
"""(?<=\().+?(?=\))""".r.findFirstIn("data: ({what: ever })")
```